# how to convert multiple files from pdf to text files using python

Tags: python, list, pdf, while-loop

i have a python script that convert pdf file to text file. 
 the system ask the user to the path of the folder that contains the PDF files.

the problem is that the script just convert one file  , what  need is to make the script convert all the PDF files that exist in the specified directory.

> the script list all the existing files in the specified directory but
>   it convert all the files excluding  last file

result after increment the **i**

[image]

## code:

```
import os
from os import chdir, getcwd, listdir, path
import codecs
import pyPdf
from time import strftime

def check_path(prompt):
    ''' (str) -> str
    Verifies if the provided absolute path does exist.
    '''
    abs_path = raw_input(prompt)
    while path.exists(abs_path) != True:
        print "\nThe specified path does not exist.\n"
        abs_path = raw_input(prompt)
    return abs_path    

print "\n"

folder = check_path("Provide absolute path for the folder: ")

list=[]
directory=folder
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            t=os.path.join(directory,filename)
            list.append(t)

m=len(list)
i=0
while i<=len(list):

    path=list[i]
    head,tail=os.path.split(path)
    var="\\"

    tail=tail.replace(".pdf",".txt")
    name=head+var+tail



    content = ""
    # Load PDF into pyPDF
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file(path, "rb"))
    # Iterate pages
    for j in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        # Extract text from page and add to content
        content += pdf.getPage(j).extractText() + "\n"
    print strftime("%H:%M:%S"), " pdf  -> txt "
    f=open(name,'w')
    f.write(content.encode('UTF-8'))
    f.close
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed out on incrementing the variable i.

There is a simple way of doing this in python.

Download and install PDFMiner.

Then use subprocess module to do the job.

```
import subprocess

files = [
    'file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf', 'file3.pdf'
]
for f in files:
    cmd = 'python pdf2txt.py -o %s.txt %s' % (f.split('.')[0], f)
    run = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = run.communicate()
# display errors if they occur    
if err:
    print err
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from no increment of variable `i` of `while` loop, you are also using the same variable name `i` in the `for` loop. So, after leaving the `for` loop the value of the variable `i` has already changed. You should use separate variable names in `while` and `for` loop.

Comment: ok i changed as you adjust but the problem now is that the system convert the files with excluding the first and last file. and display the added error in the question.
i will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

You created a while loop, but that while loop will run forever because you did not update the `i` value after the loop executed

Just put
`i+=1`
At the bottom of your while loop
and change your for loop to

```
for x in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
    # Extract text from page and add to content
    content += pdf.getPage(x).extractText() + "\n"
```

The i of the for loop is interfering with the while loop

Comment: i tried your answer and add i+=1 but still just convert the first file

Comment: i edit my cod and add i+=1 as the first line in while loop, but still it convert some of file i mean the first and last file are not converted

Comment: i+=1 needs to be the last line of the while loop, or the first file will not be converted because `path = list[i]` when `i=1` will look at the 2nd position of the list

Comment: ok i added to the last line now all files are converted except the last file